# Difference accessing element(s) of tuple and list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Why is there this difference accessing the element(s) of `t` when making it a `tuple`?

```
>>> t = [('ID','int')]
>>> for r in t:
print r


('ID', 'int')


t = (('ID','int'))
>>> for r in t:
print r


ID
int
```

I'd expect this to be exactly the same as the first example! Whereas populating the tuple with more than one element the behavior changes.

```
>>> t = (('ID','int'),('DEF','str'))
>>> for r in t:
print r


('ID', 'int')
('DEF', 'str')
>>> t = [('ID','int'),('DEF','str')]
>>> for r in t:
print r


('ID', 'int')
('DEF', 'str')
```

Can somebody give a short explanation? I'm running python 2.7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(('a', 'b'))` is the same as `('a', 'b')`.

You actually want `(('a', 'b'),)`

This is documented here:

> [**5.13. Expression lists**](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list)
>
> `expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]`
>
> An expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple. The length of the tuple is the number of expressions in the list. The expressions are evaluated from left to right.
>
> The trailing comma is required only to create a single tuple (a.k.a. a singleton); it is optional in all other cases. A single expression without a trailing comma doesn’t create a tuple, but rather yields the value of that expression. (To create an empty tuple, use an empty pair of parentheses: ().)

Remember, that without this restriction, should the expression `(3) * (4)` be the multiplication of two numbers, or two tuples? Most users would expect that to be the multiplication of numbers.

Comment: Don't you hate it when you start typing into the Answer box and then you see "There is 1 new answer to this question ..."?  (+1)

Comment: @larsvegas: I've added the reasoning from the python spec.

Comment: I see, thanks. Very annoying anyway. At least it has become better with string formatting not needing to put the comma every time you do something like `'%saaa' % (elemnt,)`

Comment: @larsvegas: As @Jochen Ritzel's answer points out, all you really need is `t = ('ID','int'),` to make a single tuple (i.e. no outer parentheses).

Answer (score 4):

```
t = [('ID','int')]
```

is a tuple in a list.

```
t = (('ID','int'))
```

is a tuple with brackets around it.

```
t = ('ID','int'),
```

is a tuple in a tuple.

The `,` makes the tuple! The brackets around a tuple are only needed to avoid ambiguity.